# Getting a list of elements out of an XML string in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string XML called doc that looks like this:

```
<equity location="New York", index=0>
  <bucket date="20211009">
    ...
  </bucket>
  <parameters>
    <parameter Key="ID">1234</parameter>
    <parameter Key="A">6</parameter>
    <parameter Key="B">22.5</parameter>
    <parameter Key="C">12</parameter>
    <parameter Key="BD">12,8,5</parameter>
  </parameters>
</equity>
```

I am trying to get "pameter" for a specific key, let's say 'B'.
Using:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmmldoc.loadXML(doc.content);
```

Then browsing stackoverflow I have tried working around that line without success:

```
var key = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Descendant::parameters/parameter[@Key='B']").value;
```

Comment: I would strongly advise using LINQ to XML instead - start with `XDocument.Parse()` and go from there. It's a much nicer API than the old XmlDocument one. While you *can* use XPath after that, I'd personally just use LINQ queries to find the element you want.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet let me give this a try.

Comment: Try `equity/parameters/parameter[@Key='B']`

Answer (score 0):

The example you cited is working. Just `Descendant::` is case sensitive I guess.

```
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::parameters/parameter[@Key='B']");
```

This does get you the node parameter that you are looking for, except the `node.Value` will return `null`.

In your case you may use `node.InnerText` or `node.InnerXml` to get the value.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful :)